# Library Installation issue in Google Colab

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-colaboratory

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-cf2b62201e08> in <module>
----> 1 from pyspark import SparkContext
      2 
      3 sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
      4 sc

4 frames
/content/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py in _make_cell_set_template_code()
    125         )
    126     else:
--> 127         return types.CodeType(
    128             co.co_argcount,
    129             co.co_kwonlyargcount,"

TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

I am trying to build a Pyspark project using Google colab notebooks, though this problem is not limited to colab, it could happen in any other IDE.

I tried resolving the issue using the latest versions of Spark and Hadoop, but this error comes in every new notebook.

I am expecting this work without any errors.

Comment: So, it fails on the import? How did you setup Spark in the first place?

Comment: To me works it fine with `!pip install pyspark` on the current colab runtime.

Comment: Yes @One There were some mismatch with Spark and Hadoop Directory names, and executables. which I corrected. Then it worked.

Comment: Feel free to post your full solution below as an answer rather than a comment